# Create an exception in PHP and PDO to prevent duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, duplicates

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I'm starting to work with PDO soon. I have a trivial question that I do not know how to solve. So, let me know if you guys can help me.

1. I have a form that aims to update data from a user account in a member space. This form has three fields "Last Name", "Name" and "E-mail".
2. I don't want that the user register and existing e-mail. However, if the user does not want to update their email and only wants to change the "Last Name" and "Name" fields, the PHP code must allow updating the records in the database.
3. I created a function to process the form. It is able to prevent the insertion of duplicate records, but it has a problem. If the user does not want to update their email, the function returns that there is already an equal email in the database. In fact, email already exists, so I would like to know how to implement this exception in my code to allow it to update the records when the user does not want to change their e-mail?

Below the function:

```
    function update_admin_profile() {
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']) AND isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        // get the session variables for another propouse.
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $pseudo = $_SESSION['login'];

        // p - It's the URL parameter. anti_sql_injection is a function to check the parameter.
        $p = anti_sql_injection($_GET['p']);

        if (isset($_POST['last_name']) AND isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email'])) {
                $bdd = connexion_bdd();
                $query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl__administrators WHERE email = :email');
                $query->execute(array('email' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
                $count=$query->rowCount();
                if ($count == 0 )  {
                    $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE tbl__administrators SET last_name = :last_name, name = :name, email = :email WHERE id = ' . $p);
                    $update->execute(array(
                        'last_name' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name']),
                        'name' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']),
                        'email' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])
                        ));
                        //The profile was updated.
                        header('Location: notify.php?m=49');
                } else {
                    //The e-mail already exists!
                    header('Location: notify.php?m=48');
                }
        } else {
            //Please fill in all fields
            header('Location: notify.php?m=41');
        }
    } else {
        //You session is expired. You will be disconnected now. Please, perform the login again and repeat this operation.
        header('Location: notify.php?m=7');
    }
}
```

Note: It's function works if I change the e-mail.

Thank you so much for your help.

Have nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the user does not want to update their email, the function returns that there is already an equal email in the database.

It's very simple. Just add another condition to exclude the current user from the query results

```
$query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM tbl__administrators WHERE email = ? and id != ?');
$query->execute(array($_POST['email'], $id));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's really simple.